# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTextInputValue')

Tags: discord.js

## i have a problem when I use my text commands on my discord bot

this is the code of my command :

```
const { MessageEmbed, Client, ContextMenuInteraction,MessageActionRow,MessageButton,Formatters } = require("discord.js");
const client = global.client;
const craneSchema = require("../schemas/channelSchema");
const { 
    TextInputBuilder, 
    ActionRowBuilder,
    EmbedBuilder, 
    ButtonBuilder,
    UserSelectMenuBuilder,
    ModalBuilder,
    ButtonStyle,
    TextInputStyle,
    ChannelType,
    TextInputComponent
    } = require("discord.js");
const raones = require("../schemas/channelSchema");

module.exports = {
    name:"Yasakla",
    type: 2,

    /**
 * @param {Client} client
 * @param {ContextMenuInteraction} interaction
 */

    run: async (interaction) => {

        const bannedMemberIdInput = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("BANNED_MEMBER_ID");
                if(!req.channelId) return interaction.reply({ content: `Bir oda oluşturmalısınız.`, ephemeral: true });

                interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(req.channelId).permissionOverwrites.edit(bannedMemberIdInput, {
                    ViewChannel: false,
                    Connect: false
                })
                await craneSchema.findOneAndUpdate({ guildId: interaction.guild.id, channelId: req.channelId }, 
                    {
                        $push: { channelBanned: { memberId: bannedMemberIdInput } }
                    })
                    interaction.reply({ content: `<@${bannedMemberIdInput}> başarıyla kanala banlı olarak eklendi!` })
      
}
};
```

i dont know..............................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is simple. It tells you that the object preceding the `getTextInputValue` function call is undefined, so it can't execute the function in question (basically).

From what I can see of the code, it's not clear whether this is a command, or an event activated on receipt of a Modal.

The `fields` property is only used when you receive a modal, not a command.

You can avoid this problem by following the [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org), or their [guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html#extracting-data-from-modal-submissions) which details this point well.

You should therefore add the following condition to ensure the existence of the `fields` property in your interaction:

```js
if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;
```

So you should have the following code:

```js
const {
  MessageEmbed,
  Client,
  ContextMenuInteraction,
  MessageActionRow,
  MessageButton,
  Formatters
} = require("discord.js");
const client = global.client;
const craneSchema = require("../schemas/channelSchema");
const {
  TextInputBuilder,
  ActionRowBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder,
  ButtonBuilder,
  UserSelectMenuBuilder,
  ModalBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
  TextInputStyle,
  ChannelType,
  TextInputComponent
} = require("discord.js");
const raones = require("../schemas/channelSchema");

module.exports = {
  name: "Yasakla",
  type: 2,

  /**
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {ContextMenuInteraction} interaction
   */

  run: async (interaction) => {
    // Avoid executing the following code if the interaction is not a modal.
    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

    const bannedMemberIdInput = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("BANNED_MEMBER_ID");
    if (!req.channelId) return interaction.reply({
      content: `Bir oda oluşturmalısınız.`,
      ephemeral: true
    });

    interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(req.channelId).permissionOverwrites.edit(bannedMemberIdInput, {
      ViewChannel: false,
      Connect: false
    })
    await craneSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
      guildId: interaction.guild.id,
      channelId: req.channelId
    }, {
      $push: {
        channelBanned: {
          memberId: bannedMemberIdInput
        }
      }
    })
    interaction.reply({
      content: `<@${bannedMemberIdInput}> başarıyla kanala banlı olarak eklendi!`
    })

  }
};
```

Comment: that didn't work
I am trying to use Application Message Command.

Comment: So you don't have the "fields" property as I said above!